# terminal window not closing after start command

Tags: windows, batch-file

My bat file is as follows:

```
start /B cmd /C "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"
timeout 60
start /B cmd /C "C:\Users\userfoo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe --processStart ""Teams.exe"""
```

I have a shortcut placed in my desktop. After launching a command line window pops up and executes these commands. After the 2nd `start` command, the window should close, but it does not close.

Anything wrong with the syntax?

Edit: Actually, I commented out the 2nd and 3rd statements, and, did the exercise once more...I observed that the terminal window doesn't close.

Comment: You do not need to use `CMD.exe` at all.  Just use the executable. `start "" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"`. Yes the empty quotes are needed as the first set of quotes the `START` command finds is considered to be the Window Title.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `exit` command at the end. Your file should look something like this:

`start /B cmd /C "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"
timeout 60
start /B cmd /C "C:\Users\userfoo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe --processStart ""Teams.exe"""
exit`